# problems with histogram labels and legend

Tags: pgfplots, labels, legend, histogram

I am having problems adding labels aligned to axis x and y. When I implement `xlabel`/`ylable` in the code they do not show. Furthermore, I would like the legend font to be smaller and the command `\footnotesize` does not work. I am probably not following the correct syntax. Could I get some help with this?

[image]

I simplified the code for the question, but originally it is meant to show three histograms averlapping.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[ybar]
    width=7.5mm,
    xtick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    xlabel={aaa},
    ylabel={bbb},
    legend style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily\footnotesize},
    label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},    
    legend style={anchor=north west, draw=none},
    \addlegendimage{empty legend},             
    \addplot+[hist={data=x,bins=16,data max=2,data min=-2.6},black!85, fill=black!90 ,opacity=0.7]
            table [y expr=1] {
0.944
1.093
-0.678
-1.409
-0.209
-0.672
-1.921
0.220
0.696
0.718
-0.633
-0.575
-0.860
-0.205
1.310  
0.220
0.696
0.718         
            };
\addlegendentry{\hspace{-0.85cm}\textbf\footnotesize{Metals}},
\addlegendentry{Cr(VI)},
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some modifications are needed for your code as follows.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[ybar,
 %   width=7.5mm,
    xticklabel style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    yticklabel style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    xlabel={aaa},
    ylabel={bbb},
    legend style = {anchor=north east, 
                   nodes={scale=0.55,transform shape},
                   font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},    
    %legend style={anchor=north east },
    %legend style={nodes={scale=0.65, transform shape}},
    ]             
    \addplot+[hist={data=x,bins=16,data max=2,data min=-2.6},black!85, fill=black!90 ,opacity=0.7]
            table [y expr=1] {
0.944
1.093
-0.678
-1.409
-0.209
-0.672
-1.921
0.220
0.696
0.718
-0.633
-0.575
-0.860
-0.205
1.310  
0.220
0.696
0.718         
            };
            \addlegendimage{empty legend},
\addlegendentry{Metals },
\addlegendentry{Cr(VI)},
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way I could add "metals" as a legend title so that the reference color does not align with it?

Comment: @Emmo03, you welcome. Add and play around with value the `legend image post style={scale=0.35}` to `legend style` such as `legend style = {anchor=north east, 
                   nodes={scale=0.55,transform shape},
                   legend image post style={scale=0.35},
                   font=\sansmath\sffamily}`.